# C# coding pattern question

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, .net-4.0

I had the following code:

```
protected void Initialize(){
  this.Fonts.Initialize();
  this.Screens.Initialize();
  this.Menu.Initialize();
}

protected void Update(){
  this.Screens.Update();
  this.Menu.Update();
}
```

After writing this, I re-factored the code to:

```
protected void Initialize(){
  this.CallMethod<INeedInitialization>(
  (i) => { i.Initialize(); }
  , this.Fonts, this.Screens, this.Menu
  );
}

protected void Update(){
  this.CallMethod<INeedUpdating>(
   (i) => { i.Update(); }
    , this.Screens, this.Menu
  );
}

private void CallMethod<T>(Action<T> action, params T[] items){
  items.ToList().ForEach(i => action(i));
}
```

Then, I realized that in my code base, there is a lot of reuse of the `CallMethod<T>` type of operations, so I futher re-factored to:

```
public static extensions{
  // I use object type as I can have INeedInitialization, INeedUpdate etc...
  public static void CallMethod<T>(this object obj, Action<T> action, 
params T[] items){
   items.ToList().ForEach(i => action(i));
  }
}
```

Now, I can get the `CallMethod<T>` on *all* my objects, but somehow after doing this, I feel there is something fundamentally wrong with this code & not able to pin-point why I feel it not being correct.

In addition - how can I put OR constraints on the generic method to accept only `INeedUpdating` or `INeedInitialize` type of objects only instead of extending the base `Object` type?

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: I generally prefer the naming convention `IInitializable` and `IUpdatable`.

Comment: Converting collection to a list just for the sake of using `ForEach()` is an abomination!  Just use a proper loop or create a proper extension method to hide it if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 4):

[KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

This seems to be to an example of Fancy Coding Syndrome. I see nothing gained from the general routines and a significant expense in extra code to maintain, debug and test through.

Comment: +1 and thank you... I see no need for such an elaborate scheme to simply call a few methods.  The OP takes obvious behavior and turns it into something that I have to actually spend time to figure out, just to realize it is calling a few methods in a 'fancy' way.  Only make your code as complex as it needs to be...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can create two copies of the function, one for each interface:

```
public static void CallMethod<T>(this INeedUpdating obj, Action<T> action, 
params T[] items){
   items.ToList().ForEach(i => action(i));
}
public static void CallMethod<T>(this INeedInitialize obj, Action<T> action, 
params T[] items){
   items.ToList().ForEach(i => action(i));
}
```

But I have to wonder if your tangled mess is really more readable than simply saying:

```
foreach(var item in new INeedInitialization[]{this.Fonts, this.Screens, this.Menu})
    item.Initialize();
```

Comment: Or, for that matter, just keeping the original.  It doesn't need to be loopified.

Comment: Sure, just giving him alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it looks weird. The first thing that came to me was to create collections of theese and then simply loop them in the method.

```
List<INeedInitialization> InitializedComponents = new List<INeedInitialization> {Fonts, Screens, Menus};
List<INeedUpdating> UpdatedComponents = new List<INeedUpdating> {Screens, Menus}

protected void Initialize(){
  foreach(var i in InitializedComponents)
    i.Initialize();
}

protected void Update(){
  foreach(var u in UpdatedComponents)
    u.Update();
}
```

And this can nicely be part of complex class hiearchy by simply adding more items into collections without changing or overriding the methods themselves.